# cocoa spread kashrus lapesach leniency

Tags: passover, food, hechsher-certification

I have a tub of Hashahar H'aole (sic) "special cocoa spread" ("*k'rem muvchar limricha*"), a product of Israel exported to be marketed in the States. Its listed ingredients are "sugar, vegetable oil, low fat coca, vanillin and flavor". (Presumably [*coca*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca) is a typo.)  It has the *hechsher* of the [*Badatz Eda Hacharedis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edah_HaChareidis) "*rak limos hashana*" (i.e., not for *Pesach*), and of the [Orthodox Union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_Union) even for *Pesach*. I'm curious what *kula* (halachic leniency) the OU is relying on (for this product) that the *Eda Hacharedis* does not rely on.

Comment: Or what stringency the Eda requires that the OU doesn't?

Comment: R'Curiouser, isn't that the same thing?

Comment: No it is not -- the straightforward halacha might require A and a chumra would require B. If the OU requires only A, it is not relying on a kula -- it is just following the mainstream psak. Just because you don't accept a chumra does not render you meikel -- there is a middle ground (which is often forgotten) and precise words matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eda only gives Hashgacha on Pesach Matza and simple ingredients (sugar, oil, honey, etc.), no prepared products at all. It is interesting to note that the Eda gives a Hashgacha on Mei Eden only L'Ymos HaShana!

Comment: and Hawai shampoo also is only Kosher for the days of the Year and not Pesach (but that Chocolate spread is sometimes Kitnyos you have to be carefull)

Comment: R'SimchasTorah, re the spread, thank you! This one has no _kitniyos_.

Comment: Hashachar Ha'oleh's chocolate spread comes in three variants of which I am aware: milchig, pareve, and kitniot (not sure which for the latter, but the former two I have seen available for Ashkenazim).